# How to add class to multiple div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add class name like *odd* and *even* to div's which has same ids?

I am getting class name on first div but not other next div's.

Please help me with the solution. Below code is the solution which I got but it is not working as per my requirement.

It would a great help to me to find the solution.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var flag=1;
for(var i=0; Some Condition To break the loop ; i++
{
    if (flag%2==0)
    {
        $('#partner').addClass('even');
        flag++;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#partner').addClass('odd');
        flag++;
    }
}
});

</script>

<div id="partner" >
    <div id="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="partner" >
    <div id="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="partner" >
    <div id="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: id must be unique.Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Comment: yes, id needs to be unique, otherwise you'll have all sorts of interesting things happen. If you have multiple elements that are alike, use classes.

Comment: Beeerrrp !!! Uncaught exception : "I have multiple divs in a page having same Id".

Comment: See this Tushar Gupta, Femaref, Virus721

[http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4wtC/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4wtC/4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use class instead of id since there are duplicate values

```
<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $parters = $('.partner')
    //note the even/odd selector and class are swapped because the selector uses index to filter so the first item has the index 0 so it will be selected by `:even` selector
    $parters.filter(':even').addClass('odd')
    $parters.filter(':odd').addClass('even')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4wtC/)

Comment: I know but if i am having same id then what should I do...?

Comment: Can you please increase the up vote as I am not able to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery for this seem like overkill, why not just change the `IDs` to `Classes`, since `IDs` need to be unique.

**CSS**

```
    .partner:nth-child(even) {background: red}
    .partner:nth-child(odd) {background: lime}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="partner" >
    <div class="image">
        <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```